# Should JDBC.executeQuery() for multi-statement "select into; select @@rowcount" throw "The statement did not return a result set" exception?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I looks like JDBC.executeQuery() for multi-statement "select into; select @@rowcount" should throw "The statement did not return a result set" exception and it doesn't - is this a bug or a feature?

Note: My problem is to reproduce an exception when executing JDBC.executeQuery("select into; select @@rowcount") - all my out of box SQL Servers returns result set without an exception.

Note: Of course, execute() should be OK and it's second result is a result set.

Note: Already asked this question on following other sites with no correct answer so far:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d361c360-3414-40e3-ad43-47e298d16121
- http://www.sql.ru/forum/1113827

Comment: `SELECT @@rowcount` returns a resultset with one row, one colums being the latest @@rowcount. I don't see why you conclude that it should not return a result set. Maybe I misunderstood your problem...

Comment: So, it's OK that for multiple statements JDBC.executeQuery() doesn't throw an exception and return a result set from the last statement?

Comment: From the documentation I gather that **if** Statement.executeQuery that if it doesn't throw, it **will** return a ResultSet object (never null). Since the first statement does not return a result it will return a resultset for the second statement. Documentation does not state clearly what conditions result in an Exception being thrown.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String) states that exception is thrown if "the given SQL statement produces anything other than a single ResultSet object". Multi-statement definitely produces multiple results, not just a single ResultSet.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [The statement did not return a result set. Java Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348712/the-statement-did-not-return-a-result-set-java-error) and [JDBC SQL SERVER: The statement did not return a result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669815/jdbc-sql-server-the-statement-did-not-return-a-result-set)

It looks like `select into` is a DDL statement and should use `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery`

Comment: Thank you for response but this doesn't solve my problem. I updated original post with more exact clarification of what is my problem - My problem is to reproduce an exception when executing JDBC.executeQuery("select into; select @@rowcount") - all my out of box SQL Servers returns result set without an exception.